Compare 4 columns, to find changes in QTY and return result in Google Sheets
Please I hope someone can help, I think is easy, but I am having problems to find the correct way for this online. I need to know changes in QTY to get a report to know what moves what does not.
1- Column A with "SKU" + Column B with "QTY"
2- Column D with "SKU" (mixed) + Column E with "QTY"
My target: Match SKU (Name) and get current QTY.
Column G with "SKU" + Column H with "QTY" and the end result.
Here manually what I need, but I need to doit in 1000 lines and mixed raws
I tried manually, but I need to arrange a very big list.
I hope I can get help. Thanks and best regards!


You may try:
=let(Σ,sort(unique(tocol({A2:A;D2:D},1))),
 hstack(Σ,index(let(x,vlookup(Σ,D:E,2,),y,vlookup(Σ,A:B,2,),ifs((isna(x))+(isblank(x)),y,(isna(y))+(isblank(y)),x,1,x-y)))))



simple aggregation:
=INDEX(QUERY({HSTACK(A:A; -B:B); D:E}; 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  label sum(Col2)''"; ))


